# Filtering a column with a column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataset, grepl

I have two dataframes.

dataframe1 (13 columns, 10,904 rows). One of those columns are names and surnames (John Doe for instance).

dataframe2 (1 columns, 55,250 rows). This columns are just first names (John for instance).

I want to create a new dataset that contains only the rows in which the first names matches with the names in the second dataset.

Comment: Split the first data frame into first names and last names, then left-join / semi-join with the second data frame. There isn't much more to help with without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But I imagine one thing you'll need to account for is working with just first names, which may be quite common; out of 55,250 people, probably more than one is named John